# Absolute Results returns one page count when cache is turned on

Tags: cache

Anyone else seeing this issue?

This has been this way since at least 2.81 and I just upgraded to 2.92 and it's still happening

Heres what I have:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="artworks" paginate="both" limit="36" orderby="artwork-end_year|artwork-viewing" sort="desc|asc" cache="yes" refresh="360"}
{if count == 1}
All ({absolute_results})
{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This shows "All (36)"

While this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="artworks" paginate="both" limit="36" orderby="artwork-end_year|artwork-viewing" sort="desc|asc" cache="no" refresh="360"}
{if count == 1}
All ({absolute_results})
{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This shows "All (239)"

I've cleared the cache a number of times but still get the same result? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate this locally, so I'm not sure it's a bug.

Is that all the code you're actually using to test this? Because if you don't include `{paginate}` tags, then `{absolute_results}` will always be the same (or less than) your `limit` parameter. (The existence of `{paginate}` tags is what actually triggers pagination.)

Add a `{paginate}` loop and see if this issue persist between cached and non-cached.

Answer (score 1):

I am also seeing this issue on EE 2.9.2 as of May 5, 2015. I turned off Channel Caching
(**Admin > Channel Administration > Global Preferences > Cache Dynamic Channel Queries?**) and it seems to have fixed the problem.

If you want to keep caching globally but remove it in a few cases like this one, you can add `cache="no"` as a parameter to the `exp:channel:entries` loop.